# Hazelcast apparently is installed but doesn't show on plugin's page

Tags: openfire, hazelcast

I'm trying to install Hazelcast on 2 EC2 instances. My Openfire is 3.9.3, and I downloaded hazelcast 3.4 from their official site.
If I try to upload it to my Openfire, it apparently works, returns me to success page, but it doesn't list on my plugins page, and when I go to `/system-clustering.jsp`, it shows me that clustering is not available. Other plugins works exactly as expected.

What can be happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Openfire; but I work for Hazelcast. Can you try to connect to your Hazelcast instance using a Hazelcast client? Just to have a quick peek if you can connect to it; no matter what Openfire is doing.